# Retrieve Email Template from SQL and embed textbox in sql server

Tags: vba, email-templates

I am using VB6,and I have an email template written in HTML.The greeting , "Dear Customer", the 'Customer' needs to equal a textbox that holds the customers name(txtFirstName.Text). I have a function that gets the HTML from the database(using sql server 2012).I was wondering within my html , is it possible to embed a VB control like a text box like below?

```
<td width="500" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <br>
    <p>Dear + "" + txtFirstName.text</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is adding a placeholder like @firstname@ in your html content like below

```
<td width="500" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <br>
    <p>Dear + " " + @firstname@</p>
</td>
```

Then after reading the html from SQL, you replace @firatname@ with whatever you want.

OR

If you can't add the placeholder, after reading the html, replace the placeholder with with whatever you want

```
str = replace(htmlContent, "<p>Dear + '' + txtFirstName.text</p>", "<p>Dear John Smith</p>")
```

Comment: Please ask a new question about it, as it is not related to this post. Also if my answer is correct, please mark as answer so other people find it useful. Thanks!

Comment: i got the results Dear + " " +  back without the textbox value

Comment: I tested and it works. The page needs to render (postback) to show the value.

Comment: No, I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: i used .HTMLBody = strHTML, the strHTML holds the HTML from the SQL server. <td width="500" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <br>
    <p>Dear + " " + <%Response.Write(txtFirstName.Text)%></p>
</td>

Comment: Oh, So you are not rendering the html page. I update my answer.

Comment: I lie, it actually works ! thank you for the help, it was my textbox property name was incorrect. :)

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it helped